# Not underlining hyperlink in QTextBrowser

Tags: c++, qt, qt5, qtextbrowser

When setting an hyperlink to a `QTextBrowser`, I would like that link **not** to be underlined. In previous versions of Qt (e.g. 2,3,4), there used to be a `setLinkUnderline(bool)` method which probably did the job. How to do this with Qt5 ?

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A possible solution is to eliminate the underline using css:

```
#include <QApplication>
#include <QTextBrowser>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QTextBrowser w;
    w.document()->setDefaultStyleSheet("a{ text-decoration: none; }");
    w.append("<a href=\"https://stackoverflow.com/\">Stack Overflow</a>");
    w.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

[image]

Comment: Oh gosh, I tried unsuccessfully with `w.setStyleSheet` instead of `w.document()->setDefaultStyleSheet`. Thanks a lot.

Comment: @Eurydice One thing is Qt StyleSheet that applies to Qt Widgets and another is the css that uses QTextDocument. :-)